# How to extract Year from timestamp in aws glue using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I need to get the year from the timestamp while transforming my raw data in aws glue. Below is what I am trying but not working.

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "default", table_name = "xxx", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
def AddDateYearForPartition(rec):
  rec["year"] = year(rec.date_entered);
  return rec

mapped_dyF =  Map.apply(frame = datasource0, f = AddDateYearForPartition)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first convert your datasource to dataframe as far as I know, I do something like this:

```
spark_df = dropnullfields0.toDF()
spark_df = spark_df.withColumn('year', year(spark_df.sessionstarttime).cast("string"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is code in Scala (if anybody need it):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val sourceDf = datasource0.toDF
val resultDf = sourceDf.withColumn("year", year(col("date_entered")))
val resultDyf = DynamicFrame(resultDf, glueContext)
```